# AWS - Lambda Cloudfront logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Im having difficulties to get logs to print anything when requests happens outside the tests. The tests does log correctly but not the real requests.

I've read that you need to add the correct permissions on IAM profile. This is how my profile looks now.

---

**policies:**

AWSLambdaFullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "cognito-identity:ListIdentityPools",
                "cognito-sync:GetCognitoEvents",
                "cognito-sync:SetCognitoEvents",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "events:*",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "kinesis:PutRecord",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe",
                "sns:Publish",
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "tag:GetResources",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "iot:GetTopicRule",
                "iot:ListTopicRules",
                "iot:CreateTopicRule",
                "iot:ReplaceTopicRule",
                "iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy",
                "iot:AttachThingPrincipal",
                "iot:CreateKeysAndCertificate",
                "iot:CreatePolicy",
                "iot:CreateThing",
                "iot:ListPolicies",
                "iot:ListThings",
                "iot:DescribeEndpoint",
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust Relationships:**

The identity provider(s) edgelambda.amazonaws.com

The identity provider(s) lambda.amazonaws.com

---

What am I missing? Why wont real requests to cloudfront log? I can see that the lambda function is working when I try to do fetch content from the cloudfront distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Please attach below policy to the existing roles you have,

```js
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "YOUR_SID",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": ["cloudfront:*"],
         "Resource": "*"
      }
   ]
}
```

The Sid, or statement ID, is optional.

It would be worth to have a quick look on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-control-managing-permissions.html

Comment: This didnt do anything Im afraid.

Comment: Can you share me you plicy json?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan there are two issues, here.  The first is that it is likely not a CloudFront permission that is missing.  The second, and perhaps more important, is that this violates "least privilege" principles by granting wildcard privileges where they are not needed.

Comment: I do agree that not to give * permission but atleast we can find is that the problem with permission with * first then can granulate the permission